# SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Maps Timeout

Tags: reporting-services, bing-maps

We are facing an issue where we are trying to use an SSRS map-control with a Bing Map layer. The Bing map, even though seems to work well for the most part, is proving to be inconsistent.

When running multiple (~1000) reports in a row, we are getting a handful of occurrences where we are getting ‘Tile server timeout’ and ‘Thread was being aborted’ errors in some of the map-tiles.

[MapError Timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9F0T.jpg)

[MapError Thread Aborted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q44U.jpg)

Do any of you have any ideas as to what could be causing these and/or how to handle them?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to the amount of time for the timeout that is alloted.  This is a setting in report server. In my case the time out had more to do with the ports that were not open on the server due to firewall settings that I had no control over.

Look here for more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx#bkmk_MapTileServer